# Extracting data from ArcGIS Onlines' World Traffic layer

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm trying to find a dataset on road traffic flow in the Middle East.

I found ArcGIS' Online map which shows the traffic in any part of the world.  I'm very new to it and I'm trying to extract traffic data from the World Traffic Service. I was wondering if the software allows to extract traffic flow data as CSV file, that was from a few months back, and that is other than traffic incidents data?

I applied the World Traffic layer to my map, however, I was only able to extract data on the traffic incidents data (incident type, location or road name, date of start, end date, etc).

What I'm looking for is these features (density of traffic, location or road name, time, date). Which is in fact shown on the map under Traffic content, but it doesn't have an option to filter data or view them in a table like traffic incidents content mentioned above.

Am I missing something. Is there another option to extract the Traffic data as a CSV file?

This is a screenshot of the content I found using world traffic layer

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the contents windows showing the World Traffic Service layer that you are viewing?

Comment: @whyzar Sorry for the delay. I've attached a screenshot of the contents of the world traffic layer.

Comment: Even if you could, you probably shouldn't. The terms of service include:
1.    Traffic data must be used with ArcGIS Software.
3.    Data may not be archived.